# How to paint on canvas in javascript with alphamask?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a png image with white edges. I would like to make the edges transparent.

Is there a way to specify a color to be not painted - like a color key or alphamask.

Are there any examples?

For example this image has white edges, and I would like to paint two of them close to eachother without the white.

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/download?mid=4a51b1bfaba674b2ca42c60e697162c&rtyp=st&ctyp=other&ts=1202486187000))</sub>

How can I do that in javascript with canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See globalCompositeOperation, or draw it in another canvas,remove white pixels (getImageData, if white, make it transparent) and putImageData of the new array to your canvas.

Comment: I've written some code doing something like that: 

See: http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/demos/fennec/imgManipulation/
And: http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/demos/green/green.xhtml

Answer (score -1):

Convert the image to GIF format? GIF allows any single colour value to represent transparent pixels.

Comment: Suggestions that aren't really answering the question are usually better off as a comment